# Crystal report changing printer programatically not working

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports

We have an application written in Delphi and we are using Crystal report 11 for reports.
There is a HP 3 tray printer which we uses for printing. Our order form is printing to tray3 in pre-printed document, and after that the order details are supposed to print on tray2 plain paper. But its not happening, if we are doing these tasks simultaneously, instead of tray2 the second print-out going to tray1.But both print-out are going to correct try,if we are exiting and login again each time. I have changed the printer in code , by giving different printer(each tray is added as separate printers) for each print-out. But its not working.

I have given the printer name to Tcrepe (crystal report component in delphi) for changing the printer, is there anything else do?.
Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add Delphi as a tag to your question, you'll get more answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the report in Crystal and point it to that 2nd printer/tray. Once saved in the report, you shouldn't have a problem.